# How much results in Calabi-Yau manifolds and mirror symmetry depends on the existence of a ricci-flat metric?

Tags: complex-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, mirror-symmetry

An important result of CY manifold is the CY theorem, it talks about the existence of a ricci-flat metric. However, this theorem and its proof are highly analytic.

There are many results about arithmetic aspect of CY manifold and mirror symmetry. My question is, how much of them need the existence of CY metric to prove, and how much of them only need the topological condition "the first chern class is 0" straightly?

Comment: You will probably want to assume the first Chern class is zero and the manifold is compact and admits a Kaehler metric; non-Kaehler CYs are very different.

Comment: I know little about this, but as I understand, the particular CY metric is fundamental in formulating the notion of special Lagrangian, and so the Ricci aspect is crucial for the SYZ conjecture in mirror symmetry.